# What Does the 'Chrono Gear' Do?

Tags: captain-jameson, captain-successor

I just came across a part I haven't seen before: the *Chrono Gear*

I stuck it on the back of my ship so I could bring it back to base, but I have no idea what it does.  Anybody know?

[image: Chrono Gear]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrono Gear will boost the speed of any parts attached to it.  The effect will transfer through all connected pieces, not just directly adjacent ones.

According to the [Captain Successor Wiki](http://captainforever.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Successor)

> This module will speed up the rate of everything attached to it, directly or indirectly, by a factor of 1.5 (this includes other Chrono Gears). Higher levels do not give extra rate boosts, but they do have more health and are heavier. The bonus extends to modules not directly connected to a Chrono Gear as well, ex: as long as one girder is connected to one, you can extend off of it and the speed bonus will be continued. This also allows multiple Chrono Gears to be daisy-chained for very high speed boosts.